# Eth.getTransactionReceipt sometimes shows 'root' value in response instead of 'status'. why?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using Geth 1.9.0. While fetching the value for eth.getTransactionreceipt, I am  not getting 'status' in response. Instead i am getting 'Root' field in response.
Why status is not getting displayed?

Answer (score 2):

The original Ethereum implementation only has root field in the transaction receipt.

After [EIP 658: Embedding transaction status code in receipts](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-658) it was replaced with status field.

> .. we propose to replace the intermediate state root .. with the return status (1 for success, 0 for failure). This both allows callers to determine success status, and remedies the previous omission of return data from the receipt.

The changes proposed were deployed as part of the [byzantium fork](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-609), so prior transactions has a root state field and later has the status field.

Comment: Thanks. I have initiated byzantium in the network.  I am getting this response(without status)  for few transactions(in my case txn id using the contract deployed via go binding).
In all other cases (any other txn) , I am getting it with 'status' value.

Comment: If you are testing with a public blockchain like ropsten, rinkeby, etc.  can you share a transaction hash so we can examine it. If it is a private testnet I'd check if the transactions were prior to the fork, otherwise seems a bug in the geth client.